# Functions returning pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, class

C++ noob here. I have a very basic question about a construct I found in the C++ book I am reading.

```
// class declaration
class CStr {
  char sData[256];
 public:
  char* get(void);
};

// implementation of the function
char* CStr::get(void) {
  return sData;
}
```

So the `Cstr::get` function is obviously meant to return a character pointer, but the function is passing what looks like the value (`return sData`). Does C++ know to return the address of the returned object? My guess would have been that the function definition would be `return &sData`.

Comment: Please get a better book, there is a pretty exhaustive list here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Hmm, this one is called C++ in Plain English by Brian Overland, and on the whole is very readable... And in his defense, he did make it clear that array names return the address of the first element earlier in the book, I just didn't put 2 and 2 together.

Comment: This is still really ugly C++ code.  Why isn't the author using std::string ?  Or is this a book primarily about C++ on Windows?

Comment: I also omitted the call to the string library `#include<string>` since it wasn't necessary for the function I included in my query. That said, it /is/ a book about C++ on Windows.

Comment: This code is ugly mainly because pointer to internal, private data is exposed outside the class. And well, it is ugly since sData isn't explicitly declared as private either.

Comment: Ok, since I am a noob, I don't know what exposing the pointer to a private class member outside the class does (I can make a guess, but this is before he has introduced the const keyword), but I will say that he does declare private data members explicitly, but this was an example to show that data members are private by default. It is an okay book, honest. ;D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For C and C++, array's degrade to pointers. An array cannot be returned as the value of a function, only a pointer can be returned. Returning the array is equivalent to returning the address of the first element of the array:

```
return &sData[0];
```

Comment: Ah yes, the book did say that when introducing arrays. Thanks.

Comment: For more information, read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/). It applies to C++ as well (except that in C++ you're more likely to use a container class such as a vector).

Comment: 6.2 is exactly the followup question I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Does C++ know to return the address of the returned object?

In this case, yes. *An array's name is a constant pointer to the first element in the array*. So, when

```
char* CStr::get(void) {
    return sData;
}
```

is executed, pointer to the first element of the array is returned. So, the caller can reference the array and do a traversal. Run the following code. You'll see the output "hello, world".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class CStr {
    char sData[256];
public:
    CStr(std::string str);
    char* get(void);
};

CStr::CStr(std::string str) {
    if (str.length() >= 256) {
        sData[0] = '\n';
        return;
    }

    str.append("\n");
    str.copy(sData, str.length());
}

char* CStr::get(void) {
    return sData;
}

int main() {
    CStr msg("hello, world");
    char* str = msg.get();

    while (*str != '\n')
        std::cout << *str++;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kevincline Jeez, give a guy a break

Comment: @kevincline I've replaced strcpy() with std::string::copy().

Comment: @kevincline: [Don't use `strncpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html) unless you're *sure* it's what you want.

Comment: @KeithThompson Excellent article. Would be perfect as a FAQ on SO :) Since there seems to be quite a lot of brainwashed people mindlessly preaching for strncpy there.

Comment: When setting the string, if the length is >= 256, you're just throwing it away without any notice?

Answer (score -1):

In C and C++ returning the name of an array is same as returning the Address of the first element in an array hence you can return the same address in three different ways :

1. `return sData;`
2. `return &sData;`
3. `return &sData[0];`

all the three statements return the same address.

Comment: They don't. 1 and 3 is the same but 2 will return something different.